# MySQL Query to order by on two fields

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a MySQL table with the following fields:

```
id, morning, evening, event, other-fields
```

For about one week, each day some event will occur either in morning or in evening. Thus the events are recorded in the table with the "day-number" stored in "morning" or "evening" field(if the event is to occur in morning, then morning field contains the "day-number" and evening field contains 0. and vise-versa). These entries are not made sequence-wise or day wise but as per the user's own will.

I need to fetch these records in proper order i.e. Sort the records day-wise in ascending order and records of each day need to be sorted session-wise(i.e. morning first and then evening ones).

Please help with an idea to order the data on these two fields.

Following is some sample data for three days:

```
id,     mor,       even,     otherstuff....
1         1          0
2         3          0
3         3          0
4         2          0
5         3          0
6         3          0
--------------------------
7         0          1
8         0          2
9         0          3
10        0          3
----------------------
```

Following is the same above data in the format I need to fetch it:

```
id,      mor,       even,     otherstuff....
1         1          0
2         0          1
--------------------------
3         2          0
4         0          2
------------------------
5         3          0
6         3          0
7         3          0
8         3          0
9         0          3
10        0          3
```

Comment: May I ask why your not using a DateTime field?

Comment: That is a nice question of you. But I don't have dates to enter in the fields. I don't know when the events will occur but I know it is for 4 days or 10 days etc. Number of days is fixed, Number of events is not fixed and dates and time is not fixed. It is just evening and morning and day number that I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one of them is always zero, the day number will be equal to `mor + even` so you can sort by that.

```
select *
from your_table
order by (mor + even), even;
```

Since `even = 0` for "day" records, they will appear before any "even" records on the same day number.

Comment: This worked fine for me. Thanks. What in case I have the same situation but somehow I cannot sum up the two fields. In case they were A, B, C, etc and not numbers.

Comment: If one string is always null and the other is not, you could replace `(mor + even)` with `coalesce(stringA, stringB)`. If one string is empty and the other is not I suppose you could use something like `case when stringA = '' then stringB else stringA end`. The best solution in your case would probably be a different table layout, with a single column for the day number, and another column as a morning/evening flag.